# Error #1046 "No database selected" when importing dump in PhpMyAdmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

In PhpMyAdmin I created a dump, then on another install running the same PhPMyAdmin I attempted to import this dump but I get `#1046 - No database selected` error message. That's completely beyond me, never seen such a thing.

I'm on Windows without command lines. Any straightforward solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When on the Export page, select the "Custom - display all possible options" radio button.

About halfway down that page, you'll see a heading for "Object creation options" and the first thing there is "Add CREATE DATABASE / USE statement"

Check that box and your export will contain the proper commands to create the database when importing.

[image: CREATE DATABASE checkbox]

You can even edit `config.inc.php` and add a line like `$cfg['Export']['sql_create_database'] = true;` to make this the default.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I wrongly assumed PhpMyAdmin puts a clause in dumps for creating the database if it doesn't exist. Why on earth not? Don't know but it doesn't so I had to create all databases manually and import dumps one by one (created manually too). Laborious but worked. If there's some less laborious solution please comment.